# How do I fix IntegrityError with UserProfile model (when User created from admin interface)?

Tags: django

**EDIT1**: I tried doing sqlflush to reset everything, but that didn't help.

**EDIT2**: I am able to create a user and specify OtherModel as NULL, and then edit the user later to make othermodel an actual reference. The problem occurs when I specify a reference during user creation.

So in my app, which is hooked up with postgres, I'm trying to extend the User model that django provides with a new model called UserProfile. I want each User to be associated with another model I created. So here's my code:

**models.py**

```
.
.
.

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    # model info

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)    
    othermodel = models.OneToOneField(OtherModel, null=True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

When I create a User from the django admin interface, I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "planamocal_userprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(23) already exists.
```

Everytime I try to make a new user, the user_id count keeps incrementing, which is weird because my actual user count stays the same.

Here's the backtrace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/add/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'planamocal',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  307.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  197.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  28.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  24.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  217.                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in add_view
  103.         return super(UserAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  28.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  24.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  217.                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  885.                     self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=False)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_formset
  677.         formset.save()
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  482.         return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new_objects
  613.             self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new
  717.             obj.save()
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  553.                     result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  195.         return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1436.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  791.         cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  735.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  34.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/planamo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  44.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "planamocal_userprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(23) already exists.
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem occurs because it appears you are trying to create a user profile and add the other model simultaneously in the admin.

Since the other model is a signal connected to the user creation, therefore, it is impossible.

Change the work flow such that you create the user, save user, create profile, save profile and add other model, save profile (in this order)

Comment: Is there a way for me to be able to create a user with a populate profile in the admin interface?